# Back button issue with WebBrowserTask in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to create an application like youtube for WP7. In this app, I have a page which list outs some of the youtube video's.(which has thumbnail and some description about video)

When user clicks on thumbnail it should play the youtube video. I have achieved this functionality by using the WebBrowserTask as I want to play video directly when end user clicks on thumbnail. So far it works fine.

The problem arises when the user clicks on back button when video is either in play mode or finished playing, it gets redirected to blank web browser instance instead of redirecting to my actual page.

This looks very bad and lowers the user experience.

So my question is how can I remove this intermediate blank browser instance on back button click?

Answer (score 0):

You can define what you want to do with the back button.
You can override the Back button in Windows Phone 7 using the next code,

```
  protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
  {
      //Your code goes here.
      e.Cancel = true;  //Cancels the default behavior.
  }
```

For example you can do two back's.

There’s a couple of guidelines you should follow when doing this however:

1. You should consider what “back” means to your user at that point in time.
2. If the user presses the Back button a second time, you should let the default behavior happen.
3. Using the Back button to pause a game is perfectly acceptable, but a second press means they want to actually go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the web page... But you can play the youtube movies directly with MediaPlayerLauncher.

I've finally worked out a good but more complex solution (mango only):

http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube